# Displaying the input before it's converted

Tags: c#

I am making a temperature conversion program and I cant figure out how to do the last part. The program allows the user to pick choose either a Fahrenheit to Celsius or Celsius to Fahrenheit converter.

This is my code so far.

```
case "1":
     System.Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature: ");
     F = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(System.Console.ReadLine());                 
     System.Console.WriteLine("Celsius is {0:F2} Fahrenheit", F);
     break;
```

Right now if the user enters 1 into the Celsius to Fahrenheit converter then it will output will be 
`"Celsius is 33.80 Fahrenheit"` 
I want the output to display 
`"1 Celius is 33.80 Fahrenheit"`

I just can't figure out **how to display what the user entered in the same line before F is converted**.

Comment: You need to store the value obtained from ReadLine() into a variable, then you will be able to display it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result of the input to a variable:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

You would then use that:

```
F = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(input);                 
System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Celsius is {1:F2} Fahrenheit", input, F);
```

---

Side note that you should be validating the user input, and use a `TryParse` method as that won't throw an exception like `Parse` will. I am also assuming the user input should be an `int`, use the relevant validation for your use case.

```
int parsedInput;
if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out parsedInput))
{
    //Handle invalid input here.
}
```

Note that in C# 7.0 you should be able to do the following that is cleaner.

```
if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out int parsedInput))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** You should also validate your Input (check if it's numeric).

```
int enteredValue;
if(int.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out enteredValue); 
{
    //Check if enteredValue has been set to your needs !
    //Store your converted Value
    double convertedValue = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(enteredValue); // I assume double here ..
    //Display the result on your console:
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{enteredValue} Celsius is {convertedValue} Fahrenheit");
}
else { /*Handle wrong input here*/ }
```

I am using [string interpolation !](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: The note about validating the input is important, however, as the method takes a string as input I believe that does the necessary validating. Although doing validation outside the method is probably better. If you are going to validate use `TryParse` though, no point in using `Parse` it will just throw an exception.

Comment: It was correct to mention it I have added it into my answer now too!

Answer (score 1):

```
case "1":
                System.Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature: ");
                String userInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
                System.Console.Write(userInput);
                F = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(userInput);                 
                System.Console.WriteLine(" Celsius is {0:F2} Fahrenheit", F);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is store the user input in a variable and then access that in your write line statement.

```
case "1":
      System.Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature: ");
      var userInput = System.Console.ReadLine();            
      F = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(userInput);                 
      System.Console.WriteLine($"{userInput} Celsius is {0:F2} Fahrenheit", F);
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of using an extra var and you don't need F to be on Fahrenheit later on you could do:

```
 case "1":
     System.Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature: ");
     F = System.Console.ReadLine();                 
     System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Celsius is {1:F2} Fahrenheit", F, TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(F));
     break;
```

Comment: This assumes `F` is a string which I doubt it is